# Deploying MEAN Stack application, hosting questions

Tags: angular, mongodb, express, deployment, mean

I'm new to MEAN stack and development in general. I have an express restful api that I have created. I also have an angular application that calls the appropriate api endpoints. I am running mongodb. Everything is being run locally at the moment and it all works.

My questions:

1. How do I deploy all of this?
2. Is it a free service?
3. Does the DB, API, and Client all need their own servers?

Is deployment what MongoDB Atlas is for? I know with .NET development, after the Azure trial was over; I was being told I couldn't have the api and client both on free tier because it's limited to one.  Is it possible to have the api with the client? I imagine in the MEAN stack a different technology is used from Azure.

Please offer advice, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## 1

I can recommend you a approach for learning purposes.
The client (frontend) you can host using Firebase from google.
The API you can host at [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/pricing).
The [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/faq) is for database host only, as far as I know.

## 2

1. Firebase is free until you get traffic.
2. Heroku is the same as firebase, but you has only one dyno (container).
3. MongoDB Atlas give you one free database.

## 3

Yes, the recommendations are to DB, Client and API has its own servers. For security and performance reasons. [This guy](https://medium.com/@nadayar/heroku-fu-multiple-servers-on-one-dyno-6fc68d57b373) find a way to server client and API into the same Heroku dyno (not without pain).